# Como filtrar una tabla con multiples columnas con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Ya intente con el codigo de W3 Schools el cual es:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; j < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

[Link fuente de W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Y intente con un for anidando el que ya esta, pero solo me muestra las ciudades que se encuentran.

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for(var j = 0; i < 2; j++)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

Y ya busque en todos lados pero solo encuentro con JQuery.

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo de tu HTML para que pudiéramos ver el problema completo. Solo con el JS podría no ser suficiente.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de la tabla HTML que quieres filtrar para poder reproducir tu problema y así arreglarlo con mayor facilidad? Gracias.

Comment: Sugerencia: W3Schools no es una fuente fiable de info. Procura usar otras como [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Answer (score 4):

Tomando el código HTML de la página a la que enlazas (y deberías incluir en tu pregunta) puedo reproducir tu problema.

En tu código la decisión la toma la comprobación de la última celda de cada fila porque con cada comprobación decides el estado de visible o no de la fila completa, por lo que la última comprobación de cada fila es la que prevalece.

Puede solucionarse de la siguiente manera:

```
    /* Obtenemos todas las celdas de la fila, no sólo la primera */
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      /* Si el texto coincide marcamos la fila como que debe quedar visible */
      if (td[j] && td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        visible = true;
      }
    }
    /* Si alguna de las celdas marcó la fila como visible la mostramos */
    if (visible === true) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

Como puedes ver inicialmente supongo que la fila no podrá visualizarse, `visible` vale `false`, pero posteriormente busco todas las celdas de esa fila y si alguna coincide con el texto entonces cambio el estado de `visible` a `true` para que al terminar de comprobar todas las celdas decida ocultar o no la fila completa.

**El código completo:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, visible;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    visible = false;
    /* Obtenemos todas las celdas de la fila, no sólo la primera */
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j] && td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        visible = true;
      }
    }
    if (visible === true) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
    background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
    text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
    padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
    /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
    /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="w3-light-grey">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PD: Cuidado que en tu código este bucle parece estar mal:

```
for(var j = 0; i < 2; j++)
```

Comment: Un buen Aporte de javascript, buen código.